# How to make a box heatmap chart (similar to a tag cloud) with ReactJS and D3JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, reactjs

Given time series data with category hierarchy (i.e. parent children), how to make a box heatmap chart like this:

http://finviz.com/map.ashx

This is very intuitive to view the performance of one stock, as well as one whole category.

Is there any existing JS that can make similar animation effect?

The visualization is somehow similar to tag cloud, but inside of a box, and with a color indicating a value change (of positive or negative).

Here is my idea.

1. We can keep the position (x, y), width, and height of each root category fixed, e.g. "Technology" and "Service" on the finviz page.
2. The second difficult part is to calculate the (x, y, width, height) for each sub-box inside of one category, to make sure that the layout of these boxes are well placed. Any insight on this part?
3. We need to make an animation effect for the delta value, and make a color for each box.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582

Comment: @RubenKazumov That's great! Is there any hovering effect plugin that we can use to add additional details about each node, beside of its name?

Comment: like this http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c37cb8e630aaef7df30d ?

Comment: @RubenKazumov Is there any charting library capable to plot line charts inside of a tooltip of a node on the treemap?

Comment: I am not sure there is the exact library, but in d3 you can do it just strait-forward. The tooltip is just the part of the node (like tree), and graphs inside  the table lines are just nodes under top nodes. All you should do is draw it. Then, you will make behavior show/hide for the parts of datagram.